# highcharts : combine "selected option" with "form input value"

Tags: jquery, highcharts, radio-button

Let me know how to combine selected option + form input value to create my chart.
Only my "selected option" (variable is "x") is available and not the input value selected (variable is "total").

```
filterCalc();

function filterCalc() {

  $.getJSON('data_salaries2.JSON', function (data) {
    var x = document.getElementById('people2').selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[x].id;

    //radio buttons
    $('input[name=BtRadio]').click(function () {
      // Whenever a radiobox is clicked, the following code would be executed
      var total = $('input[name=BtRadio]:checked').val();
    });

    //Charts
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return this.value.toLocaleString();
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: [data.annee2011[x].metier],
        data: [data.annee2005[x].total, data.annee2006[x].total, data.annee2007[x].total, data.annee2008[x].total, data.annee2009[x].total, data.annee2010[x].total, data.annee2011[x].total]
      }, ]
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: So generally, you have a select which option call json and then this data is loaded to chart? But Im not sure what is input role?

Comment: the input role: call json and changes series data (only my variable "total"

Comment: So you need to catch the event on the input, call action and use [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) or also [setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to manipulate chart.